# difference between :parent vs normal selector

Tags: jquery

Suppose of the following html...

```
<div>
<p>esrer</p>
<p><span>test</span><span>ste</span>asdlfk</p>
</div>
```

Now comparing with the following two methods:

using :parent [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jh3ME/)

```
$("span:parent").fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```

without using :parent [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jh3ME/1/)

```
$("span").fadeTo(1500, 0.3);
```

**Results the same.**

I'm curious about the `:parent` pseudo class added in jquery extension and how does this work?

Comment: @Jack - but it won't look any different with an empty span because the empty span won't be visible so you won't see a different on `fadeTo()`.

Comment: @Jack - which is why I had to add my comment because you didn't explain that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:parent    Select all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text).
This is the inverse of :empty

:parent = not :empty

Answer (score 2):

How this selector works is better explained when using something else than `.fadeTo()`. For instance:

HTML:

```
<span>I am a parent</span><span></span>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('span').not(':parent').text('I am not a parent');
```

Only the second span will be updated with the text "I am not a parent"; this is because only non-empty elements are considered to be parents and the second span is empty.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/quhum/1/)

Answer (score 0):

From the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)**:

> :parent selector select all elements that have at least one child node (either an
>   element or text).

So in your case, the selector `$("span:parent")` will match any span that has text inside which are `<span>test</span>` and `<span>ste</span>`